# Umbraco 4.5.2 admin UI broken

Tags: user-interface, admin, umbraco

The Umbraco admin interface is broken for me, and in IE8 it shows couple of javascript errors. For a few hours it worked fine, but suddenly the css/style file appears to have gotten corrupted.

I had just finished with Master and home pages for my site, so I don't think it is related to my changes :).

Does any one know how to restore the css/style of admin interface?

I tried and reinstall 3 times, but after couple of hours it again behaves the same. It is frustrating as I am unable to develop further with out admin UI.
Does any one have any solutions?

I had raised this at http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/12166-Admin-UI-Interface-is-broken-452#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the reply. This might me be little late to answer this but I start from scratch once again to get over this issue. The issue started when I tried to upgrade from previous version to latest but some reason it crashed while upgrading. Another possibility was that I might have a different local version than on live site and without realising the differences I replace some of the folders.

God knows what had happened but after couple of weeks of trial, I just start over from scratch. Until today I have not seen the issue again.

Thanks once again.
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to this bug?

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/10555-Missing-icons-in-backend-45-(nadagif)

Comment: Marko, I clean the whole app_data folder and upload a clean app_data, but still the same issue. I am hosting on a shared hosting and not sure if it is being cached in temp.net folders.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had this issue and found that deleting the CacheDependency folder did not work for me. However, deleting the TEMP folder in the App_Data folder did work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of error. It turned out my Media library was a bit corrupt, so by deleting most of it the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the application pool user has access to the App_Data folder.

Then increment the version number in /config/ClientDependency.config.

You can also try to access your page with the following url: http://yourdomain.com/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true